# Hibernate not returning data from mysql table with spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a table in my MySQL database which I am trying to access using Hibernate in my spring boot controller class. The table name in the MySQL database is `AdminTable`. (I also have another table in my database).

I am not getting the data back from my database. What am I doing wrong?

**MainController.java**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "adminService")
    private AdminService adminService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/admin_login")
    public String loginAdmin(@RequestBody LoginInformation loginInformation) {
        System.out.println(loginInformation.getUsername() + " " + loginInformation.getPassword());
        String adminFound = "false";
        Iterable<Admin> admins = adminService.findAll();
        for (Admin admin : admins) {
            if (admin.getUsername().equals(loginInformation.getUsername()) &&
                    admin.getPassword().equals(loginInformation.getPassword())) {
                adminFound = "true";
                break;
            }
        }
        return adminFound;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payment_system
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=myPass
```

**AdminService.java**

```
public interface AdminService extends CrudRepository<Admin, Long> {}
```

The `findAll` method is not returning any data. Please advise.

Comment: What about other tables? Where did you define package to scan for JPA's entityManager?

Comment: And what should it return? You are creating new tables at startup so there will be no data.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure hibernate properties into application.properties file. you can follow below code :-

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/concretepage
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```